# Change Panel Size dynamically from right to left

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using this code to change panel size dynamically.

```
    timer1.Start();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        x =panel2.Size.Width;
        y = panel2.Size.Height;
        panel2.Size = new Size(x + 10, y);
        if (x>150)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that my panel is strating to change size and get bigger from left to right. But i need to place my panel some where left in my form. So i need to get bigger from RIGHT to LEFT.

Comment: So you want the right side of your panel to stay at the same location while the left side of you panel moves toward the left side of your forms?

Comment: Right thats exactly what i want.Is it possible?

Comment: Set the bounds to `panel2.Bounds = new rectangle(panel2.Left - 10, panel2.Top, panel2.Width + 10 , panel2.Height);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that.

But as a workaround try to move the panel from Right to Left by changing panel location as well.

```
    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = panel2.Size.Width;
        int y = panel2.Size.Height;
        panel2.Size = new Size(x + 10, y);
        panel2.Location = new Point(panel2.Location.X - 10, panel2.Location.Y);
        if (x>150)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: With this code my panel is getting smaller. But it doesnt get bigger from right to left when its going on 0 location

Comment: Did you try it? the code has nothing to do with panel size. It will only change panel location by moving it left when panel get bigger.

Comment: @Mhd if you put the OP code around your line probably it will be clearer.

Comment: I did. Thanks @Steve

Comment: best put both in one line and set the Bounds!